# Redirect specific folder in a document library to a different folder -SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have 2 different document libraries, for example library A and Library B. When i click on some folders (Not all) in Library A it should redirect me to a different folder in Library B. Hope this is feasible using a CEWP in share point any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,you can apply JavaScript or jQuery in CWEP and can manipulate the links.

Comment: Can you please provide a sample code for me to look into